# Differentiating: quotient rule problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to figure out this problem and for some reason I am getting an extra number from what the answer in the book says it is. This is all the work I did.

> 19. $$f(x)=\frac{x^2+x-1}{x^2-1}$$
>
>     $$\frac{\left(x^2-1\right)(2x+1)-\left(x^2+x-1\right)(2x)}{\left(x^2-1\right)^2}$$
>
>     $$\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
>           \hline1&x^2&-1\\
>           \hline2x&2x^3&-2x\\
>           \hline&x^2&-1
>           \end{array}$$
>
>     $$2x^3+x^2-2x-1+\left(-x^2-x+1\right)(2x)\\[10pt]
>           2x^3+x^2-2x-1-2x^3-2x^2+2x$$
>
>     My answer: $$\frac{x^2-1-2x^2}{\left(x^2-1\right)^2}$$
>
>     Book answer: $$\boxed{\frac{-x^2+1}{\left(x^2-1\right)^2}}$$

Comment: Your answer is correct. You just did not simplify your numerator. Note that it contains $x^2-2x^2$ which simplifies to $-x^2$

Comment: Does the book answer have a set of parentheses around the numerator with a minus outside them?

Comment: Yes it does, I forgot to write that on the paper

Answer (score 2):

heres what i do:

$$
f(x) = \frac{x^2+x-1}{x^2-1}
$$

$$
f'(x) = \frac{(2x+1)(x^2-1) - (2x)(x^2+x-1)}{(x^2-1)^2}
$$

$$
f'(x) = \frac{2x^3 - 2x + x^2 - 1 + (-2x^3 - 2x^2 + 2x)}{(x^2-1)^2}
$$

simplify to get
$$
f'(x) = \frac{-x^2 -1}{(x^2-1)^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You basically have it. You just need to do it over again paying closer attention to your arithmetic and sign changes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand what I did wrong, I just didn't simply it out far enough. Thanks for the help everyone, I really appreciate it